# create a hidden input for list and send it back to post in mvc core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to pass a list to a view as a hidden input and then when I submit the form, before sending back the data, add some items to the list using jquery like:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    $("#SelectedIds").val(something like ["1","2"]);
});
```

I know I can't use  input asp-for="SelectedIds" type="hidden", as it return the value as "1,2".

Any thoughts?

Comment: `it return the value as "1,2".` Whats wrong with this? You can convert this into a list in your controller method.

Comment: nothing is wrong. I wonder if there is a better way to get the list with less effort. If not, then yes that would be an ideal solution to leave it as it is